# how to copy values ​from one dictionary to keys of a second dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have two dictionaries dic1 and dic2 in this format:

```
dic1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
dic2 = {'c':3, 'd':4}
```

I would love to obtain a dic3 with same key of dic2 and values of dic1:

```
dic3 = {'c':1, 'd':2}
```

How can I combine the keys of dic2 with the values of dic1 to create the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip keys of second dict with values of the first dict and call `dict` on the result:

```
dic3 = dict(zip(dic2.keys(), dic1.values()))
# dic3 = dict(zip(dic2, dic1.values()))
print (dic3)
{'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

---

```
dic3 = {k : v for k, v in zip(dic2.keys(), dic1.values())}
print (dic3)
{'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the `keys` of one dictionary with the `values` of the other:

```
>>> dic1 = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> dic2 = {'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> dict(zip(dic2.keys(), dic1.values()))
{'c': 1, 'd': 2}
```

(Note that you technically don't need the `.keys()` call for the first arg, since iterating over a dictionary gives you the keys anyway, but I think it makes the intent of the code a little clearer.)